# Use regex in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, regex

Can I use regex in SQL Server 2014? For example I have a column `mobilenumber` contains 7 rows with 8 digit numbers, like 66658697, 25365869 and so on.

How can I find all rows that contains n times of 6 for example?

Comment: NB: There is no REGEX in SQL (unless you define CLR functions).  However, PATINDEX does something similar...

Answer (score 4):

Find 4 or more 6:

```
select * from t where f like '%6%6%6%6%'
```

Find exactly 4 x 6:

```
select * from t where len(replace(f, '6', '')) = len(f) - 4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a complex pattern to search for, then you can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE mobilenumber LIKE '%666%'
```

Although, if you have a more complicated pattern you want to search for then you can take a look at [**`PATINDEX`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you want numbers that contain 3 sixes, you can use `like`:

```
where mobilenumber like '%6%6%6%'
```

If you want them together, the remove the `%`s between the sixes.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,mobilenumber varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'66658697'),
(2,'25365869')

Select *
 From @YourTable
 Where Len(mobilenumber)-Len(Replace(mobilenumber,'6',''))=2
```

Returns

```
ID  mobilenumber
2   25365869
```